# Gulp replace not renaming files but does replace file contents

Tags: javascript, gulp, gruntjs

I have the following gulp task which I want to change the filename and contents of a file replacing any matching strings with the replacement.

The matching strings in the file contents get changed, but the file's name does not. I thought it would as my code appears to match the examples on https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-replace

What am I doing wrong?

```
function renameFileContents() {

  return gulp.src([
    '**/*',
    '!.github/**',
    '!languages/**',
    '!node_modules/**',
    '!.babelrc',
    '!.editconfig',
    '!.gitignore',
    '!.travis.yml',
    '!CHANGELOG.md',
    '!codesniffer.ruleset.xml',
    '!composer.json',
    '!composer.lock',
    '!config.yml',
    '!config-default.yml',
    '!gulpfile.babel.js',
    '!MIT-LICENSE.txt',
    '!package-lock.json',
    '!package.json',
    '!phpunit.xml.dist',
    '!README.md',
    '!webpack.config.js'
  ])
    .pipe($.replace('BigTest', 'Tester'))
    .pipe($.replace('Bigtest', 'Tester'))
    .pipe($.replace('bigtest', 'tester'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));

}
```

Comment: Which filenames do you want to replace, and what should they be replaced by?

Comment: Every file not in the excluded list and replacing the 3 strings shown in the .replace lines in the code.

Comment: Between `.src` and `.dest` gulp use its own filesystem, you need something like `gulp-rename`

Answer (score 3):

Use `gulp-rename` to alter filenames. Add:

```js
const rename = require('gulp-rename');
```

and before `.pipe(gulp.dest('./'));`:

```js
.pipe(
    rename(function(path) {
        path.basename = path.basename.replace(/BigTest|Bigtest|bigtest/, function(matched) {
            return { BigTest: 'Tester', Bigtest: 'Tester', bigtest: 'tester' }[matched];
        });
    })
)
```

Comment: Ah - nearly there. I now have duplicate files, with the old and new name, this seems to create new files rather than amend the names of the existing files?

Answer (score 0):

You asked in a comment why new files are created (with the new names) but the original files still remain.  Why does gulp-rename not actually rename the original files as you might expect?

Gulp-rename is not working with the original files.  This can be a little confusing.

> It's called gulp-rename because it renames an **in-memory gulp file
>   object**. gulp is like functional programming, each plugin takes in
>   input and produces output in-memory without causing side effects. [emphasis added]

---

> gulp works like this:
>
> - read file (gulp.src)
> - do some stuff, modify the file in-memory (plugins)
> - commit file changes back to fs (gulp.dest/or others)

From [gulp-rename issues: not renaming the original files](https://github.com/hparra/gulp-rename/issues/53).

The suggested fix (from [gulp recipes: deleting files from a pipeline](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/delete-files-folder.md#delete-files-in-a-pipeline)) which I tested is:

```
const del = require('del');
const vinylPaths = require('vinyl-paths');
```

and add this `pipe` **before** the `replace` pipe:

```
.pipe(vinylPaths(del))

.pipe(
  rename(function(path) { ......
```

and your original files will be deleted, leaving only the newly named files.  Obviously, make sure you test this on good test cases before deleting any of your files!